# TeamCity and MSBuild Parameters for XNA Project

Tags: msbuild, xna, teamcity

How do I pass the XNAContentPipelineTargetPlatform parameter to MSBuild via TeamCity?

[image]

I'm working on a continuous integration setup for an XNA project. What I've done so far is to be sure to not run the TeamCity build agent as a service, so that XNA doesn't have any issues with creating a graphics device. The next speed bump I hit is the XNAContentPipelineTargetPlatform parameter.

What I've tried so far is passing the parameter as a command line parameter to MSBuild (A) and also passing the parameter as a configuration parameter (B).  Both in both cases, TeamCity says that the property is required (and apparently not found) in order to build content.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use system property in 'Properties and Environment Variables' section. TeamCity will put all system properties to MSBuild properties.

It's not recommend adding /p commandline parameters